# maven-archetype-plugin ignoring "goals" configuration parameter

Tags: maven

I need to execute a goal after the generation of a project from an archetype. The maven-archetype-plugin supports this with the "goals" parameter. I am able to do this successfully from the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -Dgoals=foo-xyz:do-xyz
```

But it is completely ignored when I add this parameter to the configuration of the POM file in the archetype project:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <goals>foo-xyz:do-xyz</goals>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I want to make sure I am not doing something stupid before I open an issue on the plugin. "goals" is a String parameter. Not a collection nor array. The source code of the plugin creates an array from it by splitting on comma. After looking at the code, I don't see any reason why it would take the command line value and not the configuration value. The only thing I can imagine is that there is something wrong with my configuration or a bug in a module other than the Mojo for archetype:generate.

Comment: `mvn archetype:generate` does not need a POM, because it is used to create projects out of nothing (it may read an existing POM, however only for the purpose of updating it according to the archetype). I therefore suspect that the pom.xml in the current dir is simply ignored by `archetype:generate` as far as the plugin configuration etc. is concerned. What happens if you set version to some bogus value and then run generate again? Does it fail immediately or only once it attempts to execute the `foo-xyz:do-xyz` goal?

Comment: I set the version of the plugin to 2.999. "clean install" worked on the archetype project without generating any error at all. And the command line from above also executed without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, retracting the answer that was previously posted here. It was crap and did not work:(

---

I guess, I have to concede that there is no nice solution to this problem. Thinking about it, it makes sense: when executing `archetype:generate` from CLI, Maven uses a standalone-pom that is not related at all with the POM of the archetype project itself:

```
[INFO] ----------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven Stub Project (No POM) 1
[INFO] ----------------------------------------
```

This happens long before the *maven-archetype-plugin* even get's executed. So I guess there is no reasonable way that configurations from the archetype project POM could affect the actual POM that is used by `archetype:generate` directly.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected by @misberner, the archetype pluging seems to ignore the POM settings int he archetype project.